# Disable logging for ActiveMQ in Spring application running in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, logging, activemq-classic

I have a Java traditional Spring web application running on Tomcat that calls ActiveMQ.

My console is filled up with `InactivityMonitor` log entries (see below):

```
21:54:02.759 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor - Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:61616] 
21:54:02.759 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor WriteCheckTimer] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor - WriteChecker 10009 ms elapsed since last write check.
21:54:02.759 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor - Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:61616]
21:54:02.759 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor - Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:61616]
21:54:02.759 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor WriteCheckTimer] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor - WriteChecker 10007 ms elapsed since last write check.
21:54:02.759 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor - Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:61616]
21:54:02.759 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor - Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:61616]
21:54:02.778 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor WriteCheckTimer] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor - WriteChecker 10009 ms elapsed since last write check.
21:54:02.778 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor WriteCheckTimer] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor - WriteChecker 10009 ms elapsed since last write check.
21:54:02.778 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor - Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:61616]
21:54:02.778 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor - Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:61616]
21:54:02.794 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor WriteCheckTimer] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor - WriteChecker 10010 ms elapsed since last write check.
21:54:02.794 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor WriteCheckTimer] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor - WriteChecker 10010 ms elapsed since last write check.
21:54:02.794 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor - Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:61616]
21:54:02.794 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor WriteCheckTimer] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor - WriteChecker 10010 ms elapsed since last write check.
21:54:02.795 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor - Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:61616]
21:54:02.795 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor WriteCheckTimer] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor - WriteChecker 10011 ms elapsed since last write check.
21:54:02.795 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor - Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:61616]
21:54:02.795 [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor - Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:61616]
```

How can I disable logging to console or change the warning level from DEBUG to WARN to reduce message in my Eclipse console?

Comment: Did you find something on this ? I am also searching on same.